# Why is Y uniform when Y is equal to the distribution function of X?

Tags: random-variables, transformation, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

If X has distribution function F(x) of the continuous type such F(x) is strictly increasing when 0 < F(x) < 1 (some say continuity is enough?). Then Y = F(x) follows uniform over 0 & 1?
Why is this true? I proved it but I'm struggling with the intuition. I even tried to use R but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: How did you prove it? What is it about the intuition that is tripping you up? It's easier to help if people know exactly what your difficulty is

Comment: This is how they proved it in hogg and craig.
for 0 < y < 1 
$$Pr(Y \leq y ) = Pr[F(X) \leq y] = Pr[X \leq F^{-1}(y)]$$
$$Pr(Y \leq y ) = F[F^{-1}(y)] = y,\quad 0 < y < 1$$

Comment: I guess I am just having trouble visualizing this. What is this random variable Y? 
I used the following code in R but didn't really get a uniform distribution.
y<- rnorm(100)
x <- pnorm(y)
plot(density(x))